# atkbd.c setkeycodes

Tags: c, linux

Длинная история, у меня не работает несколько клавиш. Клавиатура подключена по `rs485` транслирует байты `inputattach` на `rs232`. debian5 2.6+ kernel setkeycodes видимо не поддерживает мой тип клавиатуры, его исходник не смотрел. В `dmesg` при нажатии на проблемные клавиши пишется `"Use 'setkeycodes bla-bla"` с корректным скан-кодом, то есть по сути система видит нажатие, но не может его обработать? Помогите разобраться, как это дописать отдельным драйвером, я мало что понял в `atkbd`. Все и `evdev`, и `inputattach`, и `atkbd` написано `Vojtech Pavlik'om`. Но я не думаю, что он станет мне помогать)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    ioperm(0x60, 3, 1);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int x = strtol(argv[i], 0, 16);

        usleep(300);
        outb(x, 0x60);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вот что-то такое, читает, преобразует в `int long` (`unicode` бывают до 6 байт), вызывает в 60ый с правами. Кто-нибудь?

Comment: Извините, а какое отношение имеет RS-232/RS-485 к скан-кодам? Никак не въеду. Вы получаете символ, а не сигнал о нажатии. Если неправ, хотелось бы узнать, что это за агрегат получился.

Я с такими штуками никогда не встречался. Терминалы, подключаемые по RS-232 видел, а вот такого -- нет.

Comment: Может быть я неправильно обяснил. Есть клавиатура, несколько наборов клавиш, в том числе стандартный до 120, в том числе нестандартный(3). И вот на одной из этих панелей работают лишь 4 кнопки из 15(драйвер писался и тестировался под виндовс, там работали все). В debian 5(почему именно он не спрашивайте - это длиннющий loop, все завязано на аппаратной части - об этом дальше). Есть модуль(2 машины в одной коробке), у него есть rs485, мы транслируем байты на терминал при помощи inputattach --daemon --noinit --baud 4800 -ps2ser. Я сейчас дома, но по-моему так. Вот, между прочим ...

Comment: сканкоды в Виндовс и Линукс различаются, но Бог с ним. Так или иначе некоторые клавиши пишутся atkbd.c в dmesg. Но не обрабатываются, и индикация не рабобает кстати, хотя под виндой все ОК. Ну индикация - это отдельный вопрос, а тут не совсем ясно.

Comment: Три последних дня я общался с Войтеком. Вообщем суть в том, что нужно расширить таблицу скан-кодов atkbd.c. Плюс в ходе тестов выявились разночтения по baud, в спецификации 9600. Он там присваивает 8N1 при --ps2ser соотв. 8 бит НО пэрити 1 стоп. setkeycodes, я понимаю вашу логику, при нормальном RawSet2 должен работать. Спасибо всем откликнувшимся.

Answer (score 2):

man setkeycodes введите в консоли и вам выведет подробную инструкцию по настройке клавиатуры. К драйверам это не имеет не малейшего отношения. Парсингом нажатых кнопок занимается xkeyboard кажется вот ему не хватает правил.